# Fixed Position Nav flickers in and out on scroll

Tags: css, css-position

Long time learner, first time poster.

Here's my dev site: http://kcyc.webstuffdepot.com

I'm using a bit of jquery to add a class - 'sticky-header' - to the header of the site. Sticky-header makes the header scroll with the user. Here's my CSS:

```
.sticky-header {
 z-index: 99999;
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
 min-height: 60px !important;
 background: #fff;
}
```

I've used this setup many times with the same Genesis theme and it's been great. With this application, however, something weird is happening. As you scroll, the header flickers in and out, interacting with elements below it.

The part of the header that blinks in and out is always consistent, as though it is being interrupted by an unseen page element. I can't find any page element that is consistent throughout the site that would be causing this behavior.

I'm wondering if you fine fellows could point something out to me, or know some aspect of the CSS I'm trying to use that's causing confusion in the display.

Comment: Could you post the `.sticky-header` html as well? At first glance it appears to be a chrome rendering bug, as it doesn't happen for me in other browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to set the width and position on your wrapper div as well because you are floating your aside and setting it at a width of 50%.

Since the wrapper div does not have a set width, the wrapper doesn't know what width to take (50% of what?). The wrapper div also needs to be relative to the header position to inherit the z-index. I used the below code and it fixed the problem.

```
.sticky-header .wrap {
  padding: 10px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Trang. The width is definitely integral. I tried adding a position to the wrap, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Did you figure it out or else I was going to make a jfiddle. I was debugging it in chrome editor and I can paste you the code

Comment: Yes, thanks Trang. I had it all set. 

Then the client decided they didn't like the sticky nav and asked me to take it off. :\

Comment: Wow..that never happens [SARCASM]